# Getting index from list while iterating

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code:

```
const List<Map> QUESTION_LIST = [
  {
    "questionText": "What's your name?",
    "answers": ["One", "Two", "Three"],
    "correctAnswerIndex": 1
  },
];


  List<Widget> buildQuestionAndAnswers() {
    if (_questionIndex == QUESTION_LIST.length - 1) {
      return ([buildFinalScreen()]);
    }

    Map currentPair = QUESTION_LIST[_questionIndex];
    String currentQuestion = currentPair["questionText"];
    List<String> currentAnswers = currentPair["answers"];
    int currentCorrectAnswerIndex = currentPair["correctAnswerIndex"];

    return ([
      Question(questionText: currentQuestion),
      ...currentAnswers
          .asMap()
          .map(
            (i, answer) => Answer(
              text: answer,
              onPress: () {
                _onAnswerPress(i, currentCorrectAnswerIndex);
              },
            ),
          )
          .values
          .toList()
    ]);
  }
```

What I want to do is get the index of the button that is pressed so that it can be compared with the `correctAnswerIndex`.

With the above code I get the error:

```
The return type 'Answer' isn't a 'MapEntry', as defined by anonymous closure.dart(return_of_invalid_type_from_closure)
```

What is the correct way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `map` on a `Map`, you are expected to return an instance of `MapEntry`. In your case, you are returning an `Answer`, so that is the cause of your error.

In reality, your chain of methods starting with `asMap` is all unnecessary. Either use a C-like for loop:

```dart
final answerList = <Widget>[Question(questionText: currentQuestion)];
for (int i = 0; i < currentAnswers.length; i++) {
  answerList.add(Answer(
    text: currentAnswers[i],
    onPress: () => _onAnswerPress(i, currentCorrectAnswerIndex),
  ));
}
return answerList;
```

or an incrementing index variable together with a closure:

```dart
int index = 0;
return <Widget>[
  Question(questionText: currentQuestion),
  for (var answer in currentAnswers)
    createAnswerWidget(answer, index++),
];

...

Widget createAnswerWidget(String answer, int idx) {
  return Answer(
    text: answer,
    onPress() => _onAnswerPress(idx, currentCorrectAnswerIndex),
  );
}
```

---

EDIT: If you really want the second option to be a "single line" type of solution, you could combine the spread operator, a generated list, and a `map` method to eliminate the need to maintain an external index:

```dart
return <Widget>[
  Question(questionText: currentQuestion),
  ...List.generate(currentAnswers.length, (i) => i)
         .map((i) => Answer(
           text: currentAnswers[i],
           onPress: () => _onAnswerPress(i, currentCorrectAnswerIndex),
         ))
         .toList(),
];
```

Personally I wouldn't recommend this solution as it's less efficient and performant, plus I don't think it's all that readable especially for others who don't already know what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Both good approaches, thank you! A question: for your second approach, is there a way to do all that within the return statement? i.e. mapping and getting index rather than keeping a separate count?